# Write a base Test Class with Junit4 in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit4

Im going to write test classes with spring mvc.I think writing base test class is good thing to do first.I have already written some service classes in service layer anyone can help me to write base test class in spring mvc with junit4.I need to test all test cases when building an application. Can you explain it with simple example ?
Thanx

Comment: google it; you will find plenty of example.

Comment: writing test case class is simple. but I need to know how to configure to test before buid an application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run all unit tests with Ant builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760660/run-all-unit-tests-with-ant-builder) ... assuming you are using Ant.  If you are using Maven for your builds, then running unit tests is a no-brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing your test cases without a base class first, and then you will see the base class emerge. Don't assume you need one right away.

Comment: Excellent point - people are often far too quick to create 'generic' classes which don't really give any benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea, you can put common functionality in there, eg:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:applicationContext-test.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class Base {
```