# Continuous Integration - Jenkins not invoking WedDriver test

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I'm trying to use jenkins to run selenium webdriver test (continuous integration) but so far I've had no success at all. My setup:
- eclipse
- testng
- ant (build.xml files)
- jenkins
- everything is hosted locally
I'm running my test in parallel (1 test, 3 browsers) and this works fine if I run the testng file, if I run the ant file (build.xml) it says 'build successful' but nothing happens if also run this same file in jenkins it says the same thing 'build successful' but again nothing happens.  From this I can deduce that jenkins is running the correct file but its just not executing the test.  I've even tried to use maven but I don't understand it so the code doesn't even compile when I take this route.
Can someone help me and point me in the right direction because I believe I'm missing something.  I've included a photo of my jenkins set and below is a copy of my ant file:

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. --><project basedir="." default="build" name="jenkins_run_selenium">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="../../../Program Files (x86)/eclipse-standard-kepler-R-win32-x86_64/Eclipse"/>
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.7"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.7"/>
    <path id="jenkins_run_selenium.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../Program Files (x86)/Eclipse/selenium-2.40.0/selenium-java-2.40.0-srcs.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../../../Program Files (x86)/Eclipse/selenium-2.40.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../Desktop/Jar Files and Sources/testng-6.8.5-javadoc.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="../Desktop/Jar Files and Sources/testng-6.8.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="jenkins_run_selenium.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="jenkins_run_selenium">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <classpath refid="jenkins_run_selenium.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>][1]
```

Comment: Can't see the photo/image of jenkins.

Comment: Run ant in debug mode and see if shows any exception/error details. Refer this site - http://www.allapplabs.com/ant/ant_command_line.htm

Answer (score 0):

I can explain you the way I have done it in jenkins, maven and code. It should be pretty much similar with ant. This should certainly make jenkins fire your tests.

In code:
Create test suite class like below

`@RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses
    ({
           Test1.class,
           Test2.class
    })
    public class UnitTestSuite{}`

In maven: use maven-surefire-plugin in pom.xml as below:

```
            <!-- TEST -->
        <plugin>
            <!-- Runs the unit tests. -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/UnitTestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>                 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and finally in jenkins build section set goals as

```
clean install -e -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all your help but unfortunately I've not been able to find a solution as yet.  I tried to work with Ganesh's suggestion but nothing yet.  Thanks anyway

Comment: @user2389482 did you tried with adding 'test' target in ant?

Comment: Thanks much Ganesh, I will try that and post again to let you know

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your ant file by adding  in target "jenkins_run_selenium" as below:

```
<target name="jenkins_run_selenium">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
<test name="tests.MyUnitTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="jenkins_run_selenium.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760714/1712272 if you want to run all tests in batch